# converting the matlab scrambler and descrambler to c code

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to convert the scrambler and descrambler to c [matlab link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.scrambler-system-object.html), the scrambler part was done as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* Binary scramble
   input: array of size *size* to be processed 
   output: array to store the result, must be as big as input 
   poly: polynom to use: array of *order* size
   state: internal state: array of *order* size
   order: order of polynom       
   */
void scramble (uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output,size_t size, uint8_t *poly, uint8_t *state, size_t order)
{    
    /* ignore the order 0 */
    poly++;
    state++;
    order--;

    /* for each input bits */
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /* compute the value to be xored to input */
        uint8_t xor = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < order; n++)
        {
            if(poly[n])
            {
                xor ^= state[n];
            }
        }

        /* shift the state */
        for (int k = order-1; k > 0; k--)
        {
            state[k] = state[k-1];
        }

        /* compute the ouput */ 
        output[i] = state[0] = xor ^ input[i] ;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t bin[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    uint8_t out[10];
    uint8_t poly[5] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1};
    uint8_t state[5] = {0};

    scramble(bin, out, 10, poly, state, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", bin[i], out[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to write the descrambling part as describe [in this matlab link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.descrambler-system-object.html?searchHighlight=descrambler&s_tid=srchtitle_descrambler_2), as far as i know to convert it to descrambler i need to invert the xor bit when i assign it to the output as follows `output[i] = state[0] = !xor ^ input[i]` and also need to reset the state back to `0's` before calling a descramble function but I do not get the correct output similar to the input of the scrambler. Should i change something else as well?

Comment: Have you checked that your scrambler is giving the same output that the matlab one for the same input?

Comment: @PedroRodriguez yes I have I get the same output as the one from matlab